# modify LocationDisplayManger class drawing coordinates

Tags: android, arcgis-android

I noticed that **LocationDisplayManger** will show a marker on ur screen the current device location and am glad for that,but the problem is that i have to do a little bit adjustment before b/c a direct conversion of GPS coordinate to my Mapview coordinate has a little gap difference on my X and Y values.so i need to subtract the X and Y coordinates by some fixed distance before **LocationDisplayManger** put a marker on that coordinate.can any one tell me if that is possible and if so how?

Comment: This is one of those situations, when one has to ask why do you need to do something like this? What is the scenario  when you will get a uniform shift in the GPS location?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the marker symbol by getting the default symbol from `LocationDisplayManager` and offsetting the marker with your fixed distance then set the adjusted symbol to the `LocationDisplayManager`.  Example code below:

```
LocationDisplayManager locDispMgr = mMapView.getLocationDisplayManager();

try {
     // Get the default marker symbol
     MarkerSymbol gpsSymbol = locDispMgr.getDefaultSymbol();
     // offset symbol on x axis with fixed float
     gpsSymbol.setOffsetX(5.0f);
     // offset symbol on y axis with fixed float
     gpsSymbol.setOffsetY(10.0f);
     // Set the adjusted default marker on LocationDisplayManager
     locDispMgr.setDefaultSymbol(gpsSymbol);
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```